Flatten a large array into a matrix
I've looked through a number of posts with similar titles but none seem to help me out with this code.
I have a very large array (1200 rows, 48 columns, 6 slices). I'd like to flatten it into a matrix.
So a smaller version to work with:
nchanges <- 4
ncat <- 3
npatches <- 6

A <- array(c(1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1), 
           dim=c(nchanges, ncat, npatches))
colnames(A) <- c("S", "I", "R")

and it comes out looking like this
, , 1

      S  I  R
[1,]  1  0  0
[2,] -1  1  0
[3,]  0 -1  1
[4,]  0  0 -1

, , 2
same

, , 3
same

, , 4
same

, , 5
same

, , 6
same

I would like to condense it into two dimensions instead of 3 dimensions to end up with a matrix where the columns are now the columns in each slice (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,I1,I2...R6) , and likewise the rows are the rows in each slice (row1 slice1, row1 slice2, row3 slice3 ... row4 slice6)
So in other words the first 6 columns are S from the 6 slices, and the first 6 rows are the first row of each slice and so on and so forth:
     S1  S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6 R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6
[1,]  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[2,]  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[3,]  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[5,]  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[6,]  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[7,]  -1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[8,]  0  -1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[9,]  0  0  -1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[10,] 0  0  0  -1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[11,] 0  0  0  0  -1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[12,] 0  0  0  0  0  -1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
...
[24,] 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1


I'll try to describe it another way as there have been a few comments not understanding - so columns 1/7/13 are from slice 1, columns 2/8/14 from slice 2 etc up to 6 slices. And rows 1/7/13/19 are from slice 1, 2/8/14/20 from slice 2 etc up to 6 slices.
So basically each cluster of npatches of rows and columns come from a single row and column of each slice. It needs to be in this format for an epidemiological model I'm working with.
This is how to do it with for loops, but I'm sure there is a significantly more computationally smart and efficient way to do this.

 change.df <- data.frame()
  for (i in 1:nrow(change.states.all)){
    new.row <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = npatches,ncol = 1))
    for (j in 1:ncol(change.states.all)){
      new.col <- data.frame(rep(0,npatches))
      for (k in 1:npatches){
        num <- c(rep(0,(k-1)),change.states.all[i,j,k],rep(0, (npatches-k)))
        new.col <- cbind(new.col, num)
      }
      new.row <-cbind(new.row,new.col[,-1])
    }
    change.df <- rbind(change.df, new.row[-1])
  }
  


What do you mean by "looks similar to this"? Are you sure? What is the logic?

I just mean the matrix needs to be in this format - i.e. the number of columns will be the first column of each slice, then the second column of each slice etc. Then the rows will be the first row of the each slice, second row of the each slice etc. (except obviously needing to take into account the additional columns)

No sorry, don't understand your logic. Please state correct expected output. And the logic how to derive the matrix from A.

Needs additional clarity. Please edit the question to include the working code that you indicate that you have developed that generates the correct answer.

I think you could do this with a square matrix (without introducing NA), but your description treats columns and rows as interchangeable which in the above would not be the case given stated dimensions. With square matrix you could t transpose and effectively treat rows as columns and stitch them together to suggested result. Viewed as a vector, your 1200*48*6 [1] 345600 would be square at 240 * 240 * 6 [1] 345600, but I've likely lost the thread of thought completely.

I'll try to describe it another way - so columns 1/7/13 are from slice 1, 2/8/14 from slice 2 etc up to 6 slices. And rows 1/7/13/19 are from slice 1, 2/8/14/20 from slice 2 etc up to 6 slices. So basically each cluster of npatches of rows and columns come from a single row and column of each slice. It needs to be in this format for an epidemiological model I'm working with.

First I'll adapt your test data a bit, to make it easier to keep track of things, and check if the result is indeed right.  Units indicate the original row, tens the original column, and hundreds the original sheet:
rows <- 4
columns <- 3
sheets <- 6

A <- rep(1:rows, columns * sheets) +
     rep(rep(1:columns, each = rows), sheets) * 10 +
     rep(1:sheets, each = rows * columns) * 100 |>
     array(dim = c(rows, columns, sheets))
dimnames(A) <- list(paste0("R", 1:rows),
                    paste0("C", 1:columns),
                    paste0("S", 1:sheets))

> A
, , S1

    C1  C2  C3
R1 111 121 131
R2 112 122 132
R3 113 123 133
R4 114 124 134

, , S2

    C1  C2  C3
R1 211 221 231
R2 212 222 232
R3 213 223 233
R4 214 224 234

, , S3

    C1  C2  C3
R1 311 321 331
R2 312 322 332
R3 313 323 333
R4 314 324 334

, , S4

    C1  C2  C3
R1 411 421 431
R2 412 422 432
R3 413 423 433
R4 414 424 434

, , S5

    C1  C2  C3
R1 511 521 531
R2 512 522 532
R3 513 523 533
R4 514 524 534

, , S6

    C1  C2  C3
R1 611 621 631
R2 612 622 632
R3 613 623 633
R4 614 624 634

So we are looking for a 4x18 matrix, in which the first row has [111, 211, 311, ..., 431, 531, 631], the second row has [112, 212, 312, ..., 432, 532, 632], etc.
Since you want your result with the columns ordered by sheet first, and only then by column (all the first columns of each sheet, then the second columns of each sheet, etc), we'll swap the order of the second and third dimensions using aperm.
> B <- aperm(A, c(1, 3, 2))
> B
, , C1

    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
R1 111 211 311 411 511 611
R2 112 212 312 412 512 612
R3 113 213 313 413 513 613
R4 114 214 314 414 514 614

, , C2

    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
R1 121 221 321 421 521 621
R2 122 222 322 422 522 622
R3 123 223 323 423 523 623
R4 124 224 324 424 524 624

, , C3

    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
R1 131 231 331 431 531 631
R2 132 232 332 432 532 632
R3 133 233 333 433 533 633
R4 134 234 334 434 534 634

We can now use Reduce to recursively cbind each "sheet" (i.e., each slice across the third dimension).  For this, we need to split the array into a list of columns to be bound, and we can do this using split and slice.index:
> Reduce(cbind, split(B, slice.index(B, 2:3)))
     init
[1,]  111 211 311 411 511 611 121 221 321 421 521 621 131 231 331 431 531 631
[2,]  112 212 312 412 512 612 122 222 322 422 522 622 132 232 332 432 532 632
[3,]  113 213 313 413 513 613 123 223 323 423 523 623 133 233 333 433 533 633
[4,]  114 214 314 414 514 614 124 224 324 424 524 624 134 234 334 434 534 634


Usually we just change array's dimensions.
> (dm <- dim(A))
[1] 4 3 6    
> array(A, c(dm[1]*dm[3], dm[2]*dm[3]))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  ... [,15] [,16] [,17]
 [1,]    1    1    1  ...     1     1     1
 [2,]   -1   -1   -1  ...    -1    -1    -1
 [3,]    0    0    0  ...     0     0     0
  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
[22,]    0    0    0  ...     0     0     0
[23,]    1    1    1  ...     1     1     1
[24,]   -1   -1   -1  ...    -1    -1    -1

To get the dimnames, do
> array(A, c(dm[1]*dm[3], dm[2]*dm[3]),
+       dimnames=list(NULL, 
+                     paste0(rep(dimnames(A)[[2]], each=dm[3]),
+                            rep.int(seq_len(dm[3]), dm[2]))))
      S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6 R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6
 [1,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 [2,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 [3,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [5,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [6,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 [7,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 [8,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [9,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[10,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[11,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[12,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[13,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[14,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[15,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[16,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[17,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[18,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[19,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[20,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[21,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[22,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[23,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[24,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1


Thanks - while this has changed the dimensions to the correct size, the data input is not in the correct place. I just wrote a comment above for some clarity

A variation of @jay.sf's approach:
(dm <- dim(A))
B <- matrix(A, nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                    paste0(rep(dimnames(A)[[2]], times=dm[3]),
                                           rep(seq_len(dm[3]), each = dm[2]))))
col.order = paste0(rep(dimnames(A)[[2]], each=dm[3]),
                   rep.int(seq_len(dm[3]), dm[2]))
B[, col.order]

Result
     S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6 R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6
[1,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[2,] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
[3,]  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1


Yes so this is almost what I'm after, except I don't want each slice's row to be condensed onto the same row. So as you can see here, all of the first rows from all 6 slices are on the same row of this matrix. I'd like each slice to have it's own row so we end up with 24 rows (nchange*npatches).
